# ¿Son intercambiables "ponerse a" y "meterse a"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-entre-palabras

> Serafina **se pone** a llorar cuando ve a su hijo Delfin.

vs.

> Serafina **se meta** a llorar cuando ve a su hijo Delfin.

¿Son los dos verbos intercambiables? ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Para completar la respuesta de RubioRic, "meterse" tiene el significado de sumergirse en una actividad con energía o entusiasmo, y suele ir acompañada por "de lleno". Obviamente, tiene un uso mucho más restringido que "ponerse a" y no aplica para acciones como *llorar*:

- Se metió de lleno a analizar el problema.

Comment: Fedorqui me ha señalado otra acepción, aparte de la que señalas, que podría ser válida cambiando un poco la frase original.

Comment: Ocurre que en Argentina no usamos esa expresión.

Answer (score 1):

No, no lo son.

En la primera frase, el significado de poner(se) es sinónimo de **comenzar**.
De acuerdo con el DRAE:
**[poner](https://dle.rae.es/poner)**

> 41. prnl. **Comenzar** a ejecutar una determinada acción. Ponerse A escribir, A estudiar.

Si revisas los significados posibles del verbo [**meter**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=meter), verás que no existe una equivalencia con los verbos comentados poner/comenzar. Señalar además que la forma verbal correcta sería **se mete**.

@fedorqui me señala una acepción de meter que sería válida cambiando ligeramente la frase:

> 20. prnl. Dejarse llevar con pasión por algo o cebarse en ello.

Una expresión típica andaluza es "meterse una panzá de llorar" (panzá por [panzada](https://dle.rae.es/?w=panzada), hartazgo o atracón)

> Serafina se **mete una panzada de llorar** cuando ve a su hijo Delfin.

Lo cual indicaría que Serafina **llora muchísimo** cuando ve a su hijo.
Sin ese complemento la frase me resulta poco idiomática.

Comment: Anda pues lo de _meterse a_ a mí me suena haberlo oído, muy coloquial eso sí, en la zona de Cataluña. ¿Tal vez encajaría con la entrada 20 _Dejarse llevar con pasión por algo o cebarse en ello_?

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, "meterse un panzá de llorar" es una expresión típica, por ejemplo. Luego lo añado. Pero "se mete a llorar" solo, no me parece idiomático.